# Laravel 5.3 Eloquent Model Dynamic Table Property

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-5.3

Thanks for your time in advance. Skip to the part in bold if you're in a hurry.

I have a following use case: every user of the app uses his own set of prefixed tables for Eloquent Models (i.e. Invoice.php for code_invoices and Client.php for code_clients). The prefixes are defined in users table (users.code for example).

In Laravel 5.2 I've been able to easily set the $table property of the Eloquent model by reading the config (or session) variable set at runtime after user logs in. Everything worked fine, including the relations.

However after the 5.3 update any config value set at runtime now returns null in the object (as does the session value). I'm aware from the docs that session is not available in the constructor now, and the suggested workaround is the middleware closure, but Eloquent classes cannot use the middleware closure, as it returns an undefined method error.

**So my question is two-fold: how do I dynamically set the Eloquent's $table property and / or how do I read the runtime config values in the model.**

Any help would be much appreciated.

EDIT:
I'm able to specify a table for the model with the `from()` method. 
This works: 
`$model = \App\ModelName::from('prefix_table')->first();`
But my real problem is relations.
This does not work: 
`$model = \App\ModelName::from('prefix_table')->with('relatedModel')->first()` does not, because the related model doesn't know what table prefix to use.

Interesting, huh? :)

Comment: Maybe `DB::setTablePrefix($prefix)` might be handy in this case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, so for anyone else facing the same issue, this is my workaround and I believe it's clean enough:

In the login controller, instead of trying to save a runtime config variable or a session value and return the next request, I've **redirected with flash data**: `return redirect()->intended('dashboard')->with('company_code', $user->company_code);` (note that insetad of my $user->company_code you can set whatever you need to pass to the session)
Then in the User's model (User.php) I checked for that flash data, and stored it in the session permanently. After that I was able to get that permanent key in all of my models. I've used User's model because I'm sure it will load before any of my other models, as it's part of the Auth middleware.

I think the problem with the original approach (storing session or config in the login method) is that the model is loaded before the middleware has run, so the value returns null. With `redirect()->with()` you're adding one more request cycle, and then the value is set before the model is loaded.

I hope this helps someone, as I was just about to revert to Laravel 5.1 before I thought of this.

Answer (score 1):

For reading from config you can do this: `$value = config('app.timezone');`
 read [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/configuration) for more

and to set `$table` you cand do this in the model:

```
protected $table = 'my_flights';
```

Comment: Like i told you, config('app.whateverSetOnRuntime') returns null In a model. It seems that runtime config vars do not persist between requests.

Comment: @quiq if the value you're needing to persist is related to the user's session, then that's where it should be stored. Is that doable in your use case?

Comment: It was the way app worked before 5.3 update. User logs in, and I save his prefix code in the session, then get it in the model and set the $table property, and it was all dandy. However session('anyruntimevalue') or config('anyruntimevalue') now returns null in the model. I'm reluctant to go back to 5.2 as I need to keep developing this app for time to come.

Answer (score 0):

I use something like this for a really awful use case:

```
/**
 * Override to allow different servers to use different tables
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function getTable()
{
    if (is_null($this->table)) {
        if (str_contains(config('database.mysql.host'), 'SOMETHING_DIFFERENT')) {
            $this->table = 'database1.sales_rank';
        } else {
            $this->table = 'database2.sales_rank';
        }
    }
    return parent::getTable();
}
```

Comment: While this might work, and there is a more convenient way to do this with 

`$model = \App\ModelName::from('prefixed_table)->first();`
the relations will not work, and that's my real problem.

Comment: @quiq - real problems belong in the question and help you to get real answers ;-) And my approach works with relationships (5.1 here), though the issue with config() might be solved by accessing env() directly though that's a bit ugly too. Sometimes ugly works if pretty doesn't work.

Comment: In 5.1 I was able to read config('app.value') set on runtime  in the Eloquent model just fine. It doesn't work in 5.3 however. It cannot be in env, because I need it set on runtime, every user of the app has different set of prefixed tables. It's not as many tables / users as it sounds.